MODBUS TCP/IP with Node js
Hi Everyone This is Suriya. Actually I am new developer. Now am trying to read float value from the MODBUS PLC and having Node js as backend and html and css as fron end. i will share the the files below. Actually my problem is that the application is reading float value from the PLC only when the PLC is on before starting the server, if the modbus plc is closed and opened it is not reading again.
websocket.js:
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const { modbusClient } = require("./modbus");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8082 });

console.log("WebSocket server started");

const tanks = {
  tank1: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
  tank2: [10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
  tank3: [20, 22, 24, 26, 28],
  tank4: [30, 32, 34, 36, 38],
};

function readFloatValues(tank) {
  const registers = tanks[tank];
  return Promise.all(
    registers.map((addr) =>
      modbusClient
        .readHoldingRegisters(addr, 2)
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.err) {
            console.error(`Error reading from PLC for ${tank}:`, result.err);
            return null;
          }
          return result.buffer.readFloatBE(0).toFixed(2);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(`Error reading from PLC for ${tank}:`, err);
          return null;
        })
    )
  );
}

function sendData() {
  const data = {};
  Promise.all(
    Object.keys(tanks).map((tank) =>
      readFloatValues(tank).then((floatValues) => {
        data[tank] = floatValues;
      })
    )
  ).then(() => {
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(jsonData);
      }
    });
  });
}

const intervalId = setInterval(sendData, 1000);

wss.on("close", () => {
  console.log("WebSocket server stopped");
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});


script.js:

function displayTime() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var timeString = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeString;
}

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);

var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

if (day < 10) {
  day = "0" + day;
}
if (month < 10) {
  month = "0" + month;
}

var formattedDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = formattedDate;

function home_btn() {
  window.location.href = "./home.html";
}

function tanks_btn() {
  window.location.href = "./tanks.html";
}

function sap_reports_btn() {
  window.location.href = "./sap-reports.html";
}

function reports_btn() {
  window.location.href = "./reports.html";
}

let tank1_params = [
  "primary_level",
  "secondary_level",
  "liqt_level",
  "vapt_level",
  "pressure_level",
];
let tank2_params = [
  "primary_level",
  "secondary_level",
  "liqt_level",
  "vapt_level",
  "pressure_level",
];
let tank3_params = [
  "primary_level",
  "secondary_level",
  "liqt_level",
  "vapt_level",
  "pressure_level",
];
let tank4_params = [
  "primary_level",
  "secondary_level",
  "liqt_level",
  "vapt_level",
  "pressure_level",
];

// Notification.requestPermission()
//         .then(permission =>{
//             if (permission === 'granted') {
//                 new Notification('Online')
//             }
//         })

function requestData() {
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8082");

  socket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("WebSocket connection established");
    socket.send("update");
  };

  socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("Received data:", event.data);
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    Object.keys(data).forEach((tank) => {
      data[tank].forEach((value, index) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(`${tank}_params[${index}]`);
        if (element) {
          element.innerHTML = `${value}`;
        }
      });
    });
  };

  socket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
  };

  socket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed:", event);
  };
}

setInterval(requestData, 1000);


modbus.js:

const ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");

const modbusClient = new ModbusRTU();
const modbusHost = "127.0.0.1";
const modbusPort = 502;

modbusClient
  .connectTCP(modbusHost, { port: modbusPort })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Modbus PLC");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to Modbus PLC:", err);
  });

module.exports = { modbusClient };


tanks.html:

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TAS-SCADA</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./imgs/tnk.png" id="icon">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="top-container">
            <div class="vertical-line1"></div>
            <div class="horizontal-line1"></div>
            <img src="./imgs/icon-tas.png" alt="tas-icon" height="110" width="150">
            <h1 class="title">WELCOME TO TAS-SCADA</h1>
            <h2 class="window-name-tanks">TANKS</h2>
            <h2 id="time" class="time"></h2>
            <h2 id="date" class="date"></h2>
            <div class="vertical-line2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-tanks">
            <div class="tank1">
                <h1 class="tank-name-1">TANK 1</h1>
                <img src="./imgs/tank.png" class="tank-img-1" alt="tank-img">
                <div class="input-container-1">
                    <h4 class="primary-level">PRIMARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 100px;" id="tank1_params[0]">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="secondary-level">SECONDARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank1_params[1]" style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="liqt-level">LIQ.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank1_params[2]" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="vapt-level">VAP.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank1_params[3]" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="pressure-level">PRESSURE</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank1_params[4]" style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 60px;">Kg/cm²</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="tk1-btns-btm">
                    <button class="mainten1-on-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_on()">ON</button>
                    <button class="mainten1-off-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_off()">OFF</button>
                    <button class="status-sphere1-btn" id="status-sphere1-btn">SPHERE</button>
                    <button class="sap-1-btn" id="sap-1-btn">SAP</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tank2">
                <h1 class="tank-name-2">TANK 2</h1>
                <img src="./imgs/tank.png" class="tank-img-2" alt="tank-img">
                <div class="input-container-2">
                    <h4 class="primary-level">PRIMARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank2_params[0]" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="secondary-level">SECONDARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank2_params[1]" style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="liqt-level">LIQ.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank2_params[2]" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="vapt-level">VAP.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank2_params[3]" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="pressure-level">PRESSURE</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank2_params[4]" style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 60px;">Kg/cm²</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="tk2-btns-btm">
                    <button class="mainten2-on-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_on()">ON</button>
                    <button class="mainten2-off-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_off()">OFF</button>
                    <button class="status-sphere2-btn" id="status-sphere2-btn">SPHERE</button>
                    <button class="sap-2-btn" id="sap-2-btn">SAP</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tank3">
                <h1 class="tank-name-3">TANK 3</h1>
                <img src="./imgs/tank.png" class="tank-img-3" alt="tank-img">
                <div class="input-container-3">
                    <h4 class="primary-level">PRIMARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank3_params[0]" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="secondary-level">SECONDARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank3_params[1]" style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="liqt-level">LIQ.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank3_params[2]" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="vapt-level">VAP.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank3_params[3]" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="pressure-level">PRESSURE</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank3_params[4]" style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 60px;">Kg/cm²</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="tk2-btns-btm">
                    <button class="mainten3-on-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_on()">ON</button>
                    <button class="mainten3-off-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_off()">OFF</button>
                    <button class="status-sphere3-btn" id="status-sphere3-btn">SPHERE</button>
                    <button class="sap-3-btn" id="sap-3-btn">SAP</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tank4">
                <h1 class="tank-name-4">TANK 4</h1>
                <img src="./imgs/tank.png" class="tank-img-4" alt="tank-img">
                <div class="input-container-4">
                    <h4 class="primary-level">PRIMARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank4_params[0]" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="secondary-level">SECONDARY LEVEL</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank4_params[1]" style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 100px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 30px;">CM</h4>
                    <h4 class="liqt-level">LIQ.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank4_params[2]" style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 85px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="vapt-level">VAP.TEMP</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank4_params[3]" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 90px;">°C</h4>
                    <h4 class="pressure-level">PRESSURE</h4>
                    <h4 id="tank4_params[4]" style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 150px;">#####</h4>
                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 175px; right: 60px;">Kg/cm²</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="tk4-btns-btm">
                    <button class="mainten4-on-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_on()">ON</button>
                    <button class="mainten4-off-btn" onclick="tank1_mainten_off()">OFF</button>
                    <button class="status-sphere4-btn" id="status-sphere4-btn">SPHERE</button>
                    <button class="sap-4-btn" id="sap-4-btn">SAP</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <div class="btns">
                <button class="home-btn" onclick="home_btn()">HOME</button>
                <button class="tk-btn" onclick="tanks_btn()">TANKS</button>
                
                <button class="sap-reports-btn" onclick="sap_reports_btn()">SAP REPORTS</button>
                <button class="reports-btn" onclick="reports_btn()">REPORTS</button>
            </div>
      </body>
      <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>

style.css:

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

::selection {
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
}



.top-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: white;
    
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    left: 700px;
    top: 0px;
}

.vertical-line1 {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 155px;
}

.horizontal-line1 {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 1920px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
}

.time {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 30px;
}

.date {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 30px;
}

.vertical-line2 {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 215px;
    top: 0;
}

.title1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 650px;
    top: 130px;
}

.iocl-icon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 750px;
    top: 300px;
}


.bottom-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 809px;
    left: 0;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: white;
    
}

.home-btn{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 700px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tk-btn{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 800px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.sap-reports-btn{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 900px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.reports-btn{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 1030px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.window-name-sap{
    position: absolute;
    left: 900px;
    top: 50px;
}


.window-name-sap-reports{
    position: absolute;
    left: 850px;
    top: 50px;
}

.window-name-reports{
    position: absolute;
    left: 850px;
    top: 50px;
}

.window-name-tanks{
    position: absolute;
    left: 850px;
    top: 50px;
}


.sap-report-exp{
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 1900px;
    height: 670px;
}

.report-exp{
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 1900px;
    height: 670px;
}

.tank-name-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 250px;
}

.tank-name-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 700px;
}

.tank-name-3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1150px;
}

.tank-name-4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1600px;
}

.tank-img-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 175px;
}
.tank-img-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 625px;
}
.tank-img-3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 1075px;
}
.tank-img-4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 1530px;
}

.input-container-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


.input-container-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 540px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}



.input-container-3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 1000px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}



.input-container-4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 1460px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.primary-level{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.secondary-level{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.liqt-level{
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vapt-level{
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pressure-level{
    position: absolute;
    top: 175px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.mainten1-on-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.mainten1-off-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.status-sphere1-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 180px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sap-1-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 340px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}



.mainten2-on-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 550px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.mainten2-off-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 550px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.status-sphere2-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 630px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sap-2-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 790px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}


.mainten3-on-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1000px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.mainten3-off-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1000px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.status-sphere3-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1080px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sap-3-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1240px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}



.mainten4-on-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1470px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.mainten4-off-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1470px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.status-sphere4-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1550px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sap-4-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 720px;
    left: 1710px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

i want a code so that while server is running and i can close and open modbus plc and it reads the float value

Would you be willing to get advice on using https://nodered.org/

You are connecting at startup, if the connection drops the library will not automatically reconnect so you would need to add code to do this (but note this issue). If the queries are not frequent then the simplest approach might be to connect every time a request is made (i.e. connect, make query, disconnect).
